# Are Firebase JWT tokens suitable to be used in GCE?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

My goal is authenticate google endpoints API with Firebase Auth.
In  web client, I have a JWT token which comes from Firebase `user.getToken()` [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getToken).

Is this token suitable to be used to make requests to Google Endpoints?
Or should my server provide a custom jwt token to the client? [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens)

```js
user.getToken().then(function(idToken) {
      userIdToken = idToken;
})
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: backendHostUrl + '/_ah/api/my-api/v1/authed',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + userIdToken
  },
  success: function(output) {
    $('#our_content').text(output);
  }
});
```

the traceback says:

`Signature verification error: Plaintext too large; continuing with the next cert.`
`id_token verification failed: Invalid token signature`

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What's the actual goal here? Are you trying to generate custom tokens to authenticate your server process? That should probably be done with service accounts. Custom JWT tokens generated by getToken() are intended solely for sending to a client, which would then call an equivalent of `signInWithCustomToken()`

Comment: @Kato in other words, the firebase jwt tokens are not to make authenticated requests to gce.

Comment: No, they are solely for rolling your own Firebase authentication. Don't integrate with Cloud services at this time.

Answer (score 1):

According to Google Cloud Endpoints [Authenticating Users doc](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/authenticating-users#configuring_extensible_service_proxy_to_support_client_authentication), Firebase token (the one you obtained from `user.getToken()`), can be validated by Endpoints by just configuring the Extensible Service Proxy.

Comment: I already have the proxy properly configured, thanks. and I receive the token from firebase, the problem is that the this token is not "compatible" with the GCE. is it intended as @Kato suggest or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, can you print out the token and decode it in jwt.io? A valid Firebase JWT that is accepted by Cloud Endpoints should have the following characteristics:
1. "iss" claim is "https://securetoken.google.com/YOUR-PROJECT-ID".
2. "Firebase" is listed as an auth issuer as mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/authenticating-users#authenticating_with_firebase_auth.

Comment: both your points are satisfied but still not working. seems that I should a service-to-service auth